# How to remove The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete data from table i am getting following error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_TradingPartnerControlID_TPGRU". The conflict occurred in database
>   "GRiDSCore", table "dbo.TradingPartnerGRU", column
>   'TradingPartnerControlID'.

```
Begin Tran
Delete TradingPartnerControl
FROM TradingPartnerGlobalGroup tpgg 
JOIN TradingPartnerGroup tpg ON tpg.TradingPartnerGlobalGroupID = 
tpgg.TradingPartnerGlobalGroupID
JOIN TradingPartnerControl tpc ON tpc.TradingPartnerGroupID = 
tpg.TradingPartnerGroupID
JOIN TradingPartnerGRU tpgru ON tpgru.TradingPartnerControlID = 
tpc.TradingPartnerControlID
JOIn messagecontrol mc on mc.tradingpartnergruid=tpgru.tradingpartnergruid   
where tpc.TradingPartnerControlID between '34' and '39'
--Rollback
```

I want to delete data from Table TradingPartnerControl where TradingpartnerID between '34' and '39'

Comment: You'll need to delete the rows in the other table first, or implement cascading on delete. The error is telling you the problem here. Those Foreign Key constraints are there for a reason, and deleting the Primary Keys before deleting the references to it would break the integrity of your database.

Comment: There is a child table that exists which refers to the table TradingPartnerControl and has values which you are trying to delete. First delete the data from child table and then delete the data from parent table TradingPartnerControl

Comment: Using CASCADE can have recursive effects in a complex database and is adviced not to use. You may first delete the records from the child table and then delete from parent table.

Answer (score 1):

As far as its very clear from the error shown. Its due to foreign key constraint on your column in the table from which you are deleting. Either delete that record first in the referenced table or use `CASCADE ...`